# SystemJs video for Node server

Tags: node.js, systemjs

Please suggest a good video (maybe with github example) on systemjs for server side (nodejs).

1. Should cover basics of systemjs
2. jspm integration
3. ecmascript
4. simple web server

Comment: This is a request for third-party resources, and so is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use systemjs server side.

Node uses commonJs by default for modularity allowing you to do require statements to load a module.

Systemjs is for client side and implements the es6 approach to modularity but is available now

Angular2 I believe adopts systemjs to support modularity but systems us can be used freely in for example bog-standard Angular or any other framework.

To see systemjs client side in angular1 refer to my GitHub repo danday74 it's obvious which repo you need.

Systemjs allows you to either import a module at the top of your file or to load a module dynamically for example on the click of a button.

Comment: why do they have a nodejs npm ? check   npm install systemjs https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: Ok had a look , this is not the standard approach to modularity in node however it clearly can be used server side (thanks you taught me something) but what the benefits are versus just using the node require statement is not clear, possibly it can be used more flexibly either simply importing another module or requesting a module dynamically inside for example a conditional statement, however nodes require could be put in an if statement. Maybe systemjs callback has advantages. Maybe it just provides a common approach to both front end and back end 

Comment: Personally I like it because of the common modular approach both front end and backend BUT be aware other node code you see will use require since this is not standard yet